# Is this statement about the conditional expectation of a sum true?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, conditional-expectation

For expectations of random variables (RVs) $X$ and $Y$ it is true that $$E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$$. My question is whether when conditioning on RV vector $Z_{1...J}$, it is also true that $$E(X+Y|Z_{1...J})=E(X|Z_{1...J})+E(Y|Z_{1...J})$$.
Thanks for enlightening answers!

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Slightly longer answer: In both cases you need a (mild) integrability condition to be satisfied for $X$ and $Y$. If you have any familiarity with measure theory, it might help you to review the *definition* of conditional expectation. It may appear quite abstract and a bit obtuse on first encounter, but it's worth understanding. (There *is* intuition lurking in the definition.)

Comment: Thanks, I do know about basics of mathematical statistics, but not about measure theory. Is it possible to show this only from the definition of a conditional expectation or are you saying measure theory is essential to fully understand the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are integrable. The conditional expectation $\mathrm{E}[X\mid Z]$ is a random variable that satisfies
$$
  \int_A \mathrm{E}[X\mid Z]\,dP = \int_A X\,dP
$$
for every $A$ in $\sigma(Z)$, the sigma-field generated by $Z$, and is $\sigma(Z)$-measurable. Hence,
$$
  \int_A \left(\mathrm{E}[X\mid Z] + \mathrm{E}[Y\mid Z]\right)\, dP = \int_A \mathrm{E}[X\mid Z]\,dP + \int_A\mathrm{E}[Y\mid Z]\, dP 
$$
$$
  = \int_A X\,dP + \int_A Y\,dP = \int_A \left(X+Y\right) \,dP \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
  \mathrm{E}[X\mid Z] + \mathrm{E}[Y\mid Z] = \mathrm{E}[X+Y\mid Z]
$$
with probability one.