# Conditional expectation of $(X+Y)^2 | X = x$

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

If the density $f(x,y) = c$  when $x>0$, $y>0$, $x+y < 1$ and $0$ otherwise, find $$E((X+Y)^2 | X = x)\text{ for } x \in (0,1).$$

How to approach this question?

Can we approach it by letting it equal to

$$E( (X+Y)^2 | X = x) = E (E( (X+Y)^2 | X = x))$$

Just not sure...

Comment: Following the links through [tag:conditional-expectation] provides plenty of useful information, such as the linearity relationship at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83854. Something looks not quite right about your last line: how did the condition on $X=x$ magically disappear?

Comment: If this is for homework, you should add the `self-study` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the expectation into:

$$E((X+Y)^2|X=x) = E((x+Y)^2|X=x) = E(x^2+2xY+Y^2|X=x) = E(x^2|X=x) + E(2xY|X=x) + E(Y^2|X=x)$$

and then you can work them out separately.

For doing that you need the marginal distribution of $X$ and $Y$, and the conditional distribution of $Y|x$, which you can derive from the joint distribution of $x$ and $y$.

Hints are:

- $f_x(x) = \text{integral region of y of } f(x,y)$
- $f_y(y) = \text{integral region of x of } f(x,y)$
- $f(y|x) = f(x,y)/f_x(x)$

You should be able to get the answer easily.

Comment: It amounts to this, Adil: when $X=x$, $Y$ has a uniform distribution on $[0,1-x]$ and $(X+Y)^2=(x+Y)^2,$ reducing the problem to finding that expectation.

Comment: For the case E(XY|X=x) how do we go about calculating thing? is it the same as xE(Y|X=x)?

Comment: X becomes small x, and it is known since this is the conditional probability of xY given X=x, so treat x as a constant, and work for Y

Comment: Perfect: $\mathrm{E}[x^2\mid X=x]=x^2$ and $\mathrm{E}[2xY\mid X=x]=2x\mathrm{E}[Y\mid X=x]$.